# Off center projection

Tags: unity, projection

I'm trying to implement the code that was freely given by a very kind developer at the following link:

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/142383-Code-sample-Off-Center-Projection-Code-for-VR-CAVE-or-just-for-fun

Right now, all I'm trying to do is bring it in on one camera, but I have a few issues. My class, looks as follows:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PerspectiveOffCenter : MonoBehaviour 
{

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }


    public static Matrix4x4 GeneralizedPerspectiveProjection(Vector3 pa, Vector3 pb, Vector3 pc, Vector3 pe, float near, float far)
    {
        Vector3 va, vb, vc;
        Vector3 vr, vu, vn;

        float left, right, bottom, top, eyedistance;

        Matrix4x4 transformMatrix;
        Matrix4x4 projectionM;
        Matrix4x4 eyeTranslateM;
        Matrix4x4 finalProjection;

        ///Calculate the orthonormal for the screen (the screen coordinate system
        vr = pb - pa;
        vr.Normalize();
        vu = pc - pa;
        vu.Normalize();
        vn = Vector3.Cross(vr, vu);
        vn.Normalize(); 

        //Calculate the vector from eye (pe) to screen corners (pa, pb, pc)
        va = pa-pe;
        vb = pb-pe;
        vc = pc-pe;

        //Get the distance;; from the eye to the screen plane
        eyedistance = -(Vector3.Dot(va, vn));

        //Get the varaibles for the off center projection
        left    = (Vector3.Dot(vr, va)*near)/eyedistance;
        right   = (Vector3.Dot(vr, vb)*near)/eyedistance;
        bottom  = (Vector3.Dot(vu, va)*near)/eyedistance;
        top     = (Vector3.Dot(vu, vc)*near)/eyedistance;

        //Get this projection
        projectionM = PerspectiveOffCenter(left, right, bottom, top, near, far);

        //Fill in the transform matrix
        transformMatrix = new Matrix4x4();

        transformMatrix[0, 0] = vr.x;
        transformMatrix[0, 1] = vr.y;
        transformMatrix[0, 2] = vr.z;
        transformMatrix[0, 3] = 0;

        transformMatrix[1, 0] = vu.x;
        transformMatrix[1, 1] = vu.y;
        transformMatrix[1, 2] = vu.z;
        transformMatrix[1, 3] = 0;

        transformMatrix[2, 0] = vn.x;
        transformMatrix[2, 1] = vn.y;
        transformMatrix[2, 2] = vn.z;
        transformMatrix[2, 3] = 0;

        transformMatrix[3, 0] = 0;
        transformMatrix[3, 1] = 0;
        transformMatrix[3, 2] = 0;
        transformMatrix[3, 3] = 1;

        //Now for the eye transform
        eyeTranslateM = new Matrix4x4();

        eyeTranslateM[0, 0] = 1;
        eyeTranslateM[0, 1] = 0;
        eyeTranslateM[0, 2] = 0;
        eyeTranslateM[0, 3] = -pe.x;

        eyeTranslateM[1, 0] = 0;
        eyeTranslateM[1, 1] = 1;
        eyeTranslateM[1, 2] = 0;
        eyeTranslateM[1, 3] = -pe.y;

        eyeTranslateM[2, 0] = 0;
        eyeTranslateM[2, 1] = 0;
        eyeTranslateM[2, 2] = 1;
        eyeTranslateM[2, 3] = -pe.z;

        eyeTranslateM[3, 0] = 0;
        eyeTranslateM[3, 1] = 0;
        eyeTranslateM[3, 2] = 0;
        eyeTranslateM[3, 3] = 1f;



        //Multiply all together
        finalProjection = new Matrix4x4();
        finalProjection = Matrix4x4.identity * projectionM*transformMatrix*eyeTranslateM;

        //finally return
        return finalProjection;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame

    public void FixedUpdate () 
    {
        Camera cam = camera;

        //calculate projection
        Matrix4x4 genProjection = GeneralizedPerspectiveProjection( new Vector3(0,1,0), new Vector3(1,1,0), new Vector3(0,0,0), new Vector3(0,0,0), cam.nearClipPlane, cam.farClipPlane);
                                                                //(BottomLeftCorner, BottomRightCorner, TopLeftCorner, trackerPosition, cam.nearClipPlane, cam.farClipPlane);
        cam.projectionMatrix = genProjection;   

    }   
}
```

My error lies in `projectionM = PerspectiveOffCenter(left, right, bottom, top, near, far);`

The debugger states:

> Expression denotes a `type', where a 'variable', 'value' or 'method
>   group' was expected.

Thus, I changed the line to read:  `projectionM = new PerspectiveOffCenter(left, right, bottom, top, near, far);`

But then the error is changed to:

> The type 'PerspectiveOffCenter' does not contain a constructor that
>   takes '6' arguments.

For reasons that are obvious.

So, finally, I changed the line to read: `projectionM = new GeneralizedPerspectiveProjection(left, right, bottom, top, near, far);`

And the error I get is:

> is a 'method' but a 'type' was expected.

With this last error, I'm not sure what it is I should do / missing. Can anyone see what it is that I'm missing to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to complete the method `GeneralizedPerspectiveProjection()` I'm pretty sure trying to use `GeneralizedPerspectiveProjection()` within that method is a poor choice. I dodn't see anything to indicate that this was a recursive method.

Here's your problem:

```
public class PerspectiveOffCenter : MonoBehaviour
```

Your class is named `PerspectiveOffCenter`. Then when you're trying to run the code you pasted in you're getting the following error:

> The type 'PerspectiveOffCenter' does not contain a constructor that takes '6' arguments.

From the code you've shown, it clearly doesn't contain a constructor that takes *any* arguments, let alone six. You said "For reasons that are obvious." But, I'm not sure they were obvious to you.

**Your code is incomplete.** You copied an pasted without checking that everything was included. You need to find or create a proper constructor for your class if you want to use that code. A quick Google search yielded [this](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/112104-PerspectiveOffCenter). But I don't know if that's the same code the original author used or not. You'll have to ask them, or figure out what's required based on your current code and write it yourself.